# Simple ternary operator not working

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why this simple ternary operator doesn't work.

```
var numOne = prompt("Enter first number");
var numTwo = prompt("Enter second number");

var outcome = numOne > numTwo ? "First number is bigger" : "Second number is bigger";

document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML(outcome);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code, `innerHTML` is a property that you need to assign a value to, not a function. You also need to convert your values to integers otherwise your comparison will not work in all cases.

```js
var numOne = "25"
var numTwo = "111"

var outcome = parseInt(numOne) > parseInt(numTwo) ? "First number is bigger" : "Second number is bigger";
var outcome2 = numOne > numTwo ? "First number is bigger" : "Second number is bigger";

document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML="Using integers: " + outcome;
document.getElementById("paragraph2").innerHTML="Using strings: " + outcome2;
```

```html
<div id="paragraph"></div>
<div id="paragraph2"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`innerHTML` is a **property** not a method.

The usage should be

`document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = outcome;`

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `parseInt` as prompt will give u a string.
2. `.innerHTML` is a property not a method (see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp))

```js
var numOne = prompt("Enter first number");
var numTwo = prompt("Enter second number");

var outcome = parseInt(numOne) > parseInt(numTwo) ? "First number is bigger" : "Second number is bigger";

document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = outcome;
```

```html
<div id="paragraph"></div>
```

Comment: It seems the string automatically converts to a number without the parseInt. Thanks for the help and heads up.